# Validation before persistance on state_machine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

What is the correct syntax for performing a validation on before a transition in the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem?

I've tried the following,

```
before_transition :apple => :orange do
  validate :validate_core
end

def validate_core
  if core.things.blank?
    errors.add(:core, 'must have one thing')
  end
end
```

But I get the following error,

```
undefined method `validate' for #<StateMachine::Machine:0x007ffed73e0bd8>
```

I've also tried writing it as,

```
state :orange do
  validate :validate_core
end
```

But this causes a rollback after the record is saved, which is less than ideal. I'd like to stop the state machine from transitioning into `:orange` in the first place.

The core problem is that in my controller I have logic that relies on the result of `object.save`. The validation I have for my state machine doesn't kick in until after the initial save, so save gets returned as true and the controller goes on to logic it shouldn't hit if the object isn't valid.

I've worked around this by testing the validity manually in addition to checking the save, but it feels like there should be a way to have the validation fire before the object saves.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The idea of that particular state machine is to embed validation declaration inside the state.

```
state :orange do
  validate :validate_core
end
```

The configuration above will perform the validation `:validate_core` whenever the object is transitioning to orange.

```
event :orangify do
  transition all => :orange
end
```

I understand your concern about the rollback, but keep in mind that the rollback is performed in a transaction, thus it's quite cheap.

```
record.orangify!
```

Moreover, remember you can also use the non bang version that don't use exceptions.

```
> c.orangify
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false
```

That said, if you want to use a different approach based on the before transition, then you only have to know that if the callback returns false, the transition is halted.

```
before_transition do
  false
end

> c.orangify!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
StateMachine::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition state via :cancel from :purchased (Reason(s): Transition halted)
```

Note that a transaction is always started, but it's likely no query will be performed if the callback is at the very beginning.

The `before_transaction` accepts some params. You can yield the object and the transaction instance.

```
before_transition do |object, transaction|
  object.validate_core
end
```

and indeed you can restrict it by event

```
before_transition all => :orange do |object, transaction|
  object.validate_core # => false
end
```

In this case, `validate_core` however is supposed to be a simple method that returns true/false. If you want to use the defined validation chain, then what comes to my mind is to invoke `valid?` on the model itself.

```
before_transition all => :orange do |object, transaction|
  object.valid?
end
```

However, please note that you can't run a transaction outside the scope of a transaction. In fact, if you inspect the code for `perform`, you will see that callbacks are inside the transaction.

```
# Runs each of the collection's transitions in parallel.
# 
# All transitions will run through the following steps:
# 1. Before callbacks
# 2. Persist state
# 3. Invoke action
# 4. After callbacks (if configured)
# 5. Rollback (if action is unsuccessful)
# 
# If a block is passed to this method, that block will be called instead
# of invoking each transition's action.
def perform(&block)
  reset

  if valid?
    if use_event_attributes? && !block_given?
      each do |transition|
        transition.transient = true
        transition.machine.write(object, :event_transition, transition)
      end

      run_actions
    else
      within_transaction do
        catch(:halt) { run_callbacks(&block) }
        rollback unless success?
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

To skip the transaction, you should monkey patch state_machine so that transition methods (such as `orangify!`) check whether the record is valid before transitioning.

Here's an example of what you should achieve

```
# Override orangify! state machine action
# If the record is valid, then perform the actual transition,
# otherwise return early.
def orangify!(*args)
  return false unless self.valid?
  super
end
```

Of course, you can't do that manually for each method, that's why you *should* monkey patch the library to achieve this result.

Comment: The problem isn't performance with rollbacks, it's more that the save goes through (at least initially). So in my controller, which powers a wizard, the controller check save and then carries on and brings the user to the next step. Meanwhile, the state rollback in the background and the user is now on a step they shouldn't have access to. I have an explicit check in my controller, but it feels like unneeded clutter.

Comment: Have you tried to return false as I shown? It should stop the transition.

Comment: I did, and it does, but it still does it as a rollback. I am going to update my question to better reflect what I am looking for. I made the assumption that stopping the state transition on before_transition would stop the rollback, but it doesn't.

Comment: You cannot do it. As soon as the code is started (and handled) by the state machine, it is already wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Ah well that is a bummer, but sometimes life is disappointing. I am going to keep the question open for a little bit longer and then, unless someone has a better answer, give you the bounty. Do you mind adding that last comment into the body of your answer?

Comment: I integrated some additional details. All the solutions are just workarounds, this tells you that it was not designed to work in a different way.

Comment: This answer is better than the documentation IMO. Very informative, thanks. Particularly the part about returning false from a before_transition. This caught me out in a major way when first using state_machine.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to cancel the transition to the next state by doing something like this:

```
before_transition :apple => :orange do
  if core.things.blank?
    errors.add(:core, 'must have one thing')
    throw :halt
  end
end
```

This way, if core.things is blank, then an error would appear for core and the transition would be cancelled. I assume it also wouldn't make any changes to the DB. Haven't tried this code though but just read its source. Given that the code above, would likely lead to even more code to catch the exception, how about the approach below?

```
def orange_with_validation
  if core.things.blank? && apple?
    errors.add(:core, 'must have one thing')
  else
    #transition to orange state
    orange
  end
end
```

You could use the code above in places where you would like validation before it transitions to the orange state. This approach allows you to workaround the limitations of state_machine's callbacks. Using it in your controller which powers the wizard form would stop your form from moving to the next step due and would avoid any DB hits when it fails the validation.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but then I have to write code to catch this exception, so it doesn't end up really reducing the code around the persistence

Comment: The code I provided above might just be the solution to your problem. It allows you to fire the validation before the object saves. You'll just need to use the `#orange_with_validation` in places where you want that behavior instead of just `#orange`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new but isn't is

```
 validates
```

instead of

```
validate
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Also just reading the documentation you have to do the validation in the state, I've never used state_machine but I think something like this:

```
state :orange do
      validates_presence_of   :apple
end
```

Comment: The `validate` call is good for when you custom validation is in a method, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate. Doing it in the state unfortunately means it isn't checked until after the .save method, which leads to some really strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is looking for a method 'validate' for state.  But validate is an active record method.  All of your models inherit from active record, but state does not, so it does not have a validate method.  The way to get around this is to define a class method and call it in state.  So lets say your model is called Fruit, you could have something like this

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.do_the_validation
        validate :validate_core
    end

    before_transition :apple => :orange, :do => :do_the_validation
end
```

I'm not sure if you need self.  Also, the second line may need to be:

```
self.validate :validate_core
```

I think this should work.  That being said, is there any reason you're having it validate before the transition?  Why not just put the validate by itself?  It should always validate.

Comment: RE: 'always validating', there is an association that isn't needed until you hit a particular state.

Comment: Didn't end up working. I tried it with and without the `self` in front of validate.

Comment: Can you post the validate_core method?

Comment: Done. Obviously I am trying to simplify the code down to what I consider to be the essential parts, as the actual state machine has many more transitions.

Answer (score 0):

validate methos is class method of your model, so you can't call him from block that you pass to state_machine class method, because you have new context.

Try this:

```
YourModel < AR::B
  validate :validate_core

  state_machine :state, :initial => :some_state do
    before_transition :apple => :orange do |model, transition|
      model.valid?
    end
  end

  def validate_core
    if core.things.blank?
      errors.add(:core, 'must have one thing')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal of "stop[ping] the state machine from transitioning into :orange in the first place" sounds like a guard on the transition.  state_machine supports this with :if and :unless options on the transition definition.  As with ActiveModel validators, the value for these options can be either a lambda or a symbol representing the method name to call on the object.

```
event :orangify
  transition :apple => :orange, :if => lambda{|thing| thing.validate_core }
  # OR transition :apple => :orange, :if => :validate_core
end
```